# Gravatar No Longer working over https

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, https, gravatar

For months we have been using a different default gravatar image for members of the site but suddenly this is no longer working.

Here is the error "we cannot complete this request remote data could not be fetched" when directly trying to reach the image located here: http://tinyurl.com/ou7tfg3

Here is what is in the functions.php file (wordpress)

```
 add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'mytheme_default_avatar' );
 function mytheme_default_avatar( $avatar_defaults ) 
 {
     $avatar = get_option('avatar_default');

     $new_avatar_url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/iBDgravatar.png’, ‘http’;

     if( $avatar != $new_avatar_url )
     {
         update_option( 'avatar_default', $new_avatar_url );
     }

     $avatar_defaults[ $new_avatar_url ] = 'Default Avatar';
     return $avatar_defaults;
 }
```

QUESTION:  How can we serve just the image as http - insecure?

Or is there a better way to fix this?

Changing the URL to https doesnt seem to fix either

```
  add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'new_default_avatar' );

  function new_default_avatar ( $avatar_defaults ) {
    //Set the URL where the image file for your avatar is located
    $new_avatar_url = 'https://www.ibodyguardsdirect.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/gravatar/iBDgravatar.png';
    //Set the text that will appear to the right of your avatar in Settings>>Discussion
    $avatar_defaults[$new_avatar_url] = 'default';
    return $avatar_defaults;
   }
```

Comment: If you decide to server even one element from insecure connection, then the whole HTTPS thing is pointless, fix the avatar.

Comment: Yeah - so how to fix?

Comment: You're grabbing a picture from `ibodyguardsdirect.com` (a domain that I suspect belongs to you). What does this question have to do with the Gravatar service?

Answer (score 6):

For https use "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/" instead of "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/"

Comment: Exactly, it's not obvious, but by looking at the code inside WordPress, this is how it works!